# Python Regex match 2nd or 3rd word in line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to separate lines into 3 sections using regex, with a typical line fitting into this kind of pattern: `-30.345 150.930 112.356`

I'm extracting the first section of data fine using `lat = float(re.match('[^\s]+', line).group(0))`, but have been unable to correctly target the 2nd and 3rd numbers.

I've tried/am trying `long = float(re.match('.*?\s(\S+)\s.*?', line).group(0))` but this is returning the entire string up until the 2nd whitespace.  How can I target just the 2nd number and 3rd number in these strings?

Comment: Is there a reason why don't you use a regular `.split()`? Thanks.

Comment: Only because I know how to do that and would like to build my understanding of regex so I can use it more frequently

Comment: You don't get better with a screwdriver if you use the handle to hammer nails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot do `split` then you can just match the numbers with optional `-` or `+` at the start:

```
>>> s = '-30.345 foo 150.930 abc 112.356 another .123'
>>> re.findall(r'([+-]?\d*\.?\d+)', s)
['-30.345', '150.930', '112.356', '.123']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXv0ep/7)